How do I find a result in an adjacent cell when there is a mix of letters, formatting, and numbers?
I don't want to go too far into this project before getting my fundamental problem fixed.

When I put in =LOOKUP(120/7C/ME,A2:A6,B2:B6).
I get We're Working It when I should be getting Cargo Chargers. If I do this with simple 1,2,3 A,B,C it comes out correctly every time.
I am using H3 as my place where I will be putting my variable search info.

@Harun24hr's answer is what you need, but I think you should real carefully how LOOKUP function works and you'll understand properly the mistake you are doing :)

I did do that... THOUGHALLY. By all appearances I am doing it right...  even using the answer below...and still running into the error.  However I have attached a screenshot of the issue this time.  Feel silly I didn't do that the first time!

The only name you have in the formula is XLOOKUP. Since you're getting the #NAME? error, you probably don't have XLOOKUP (then you also don't have FILTER) i.e. your Excel version is too old. Try either the VLOOKUP or the more flexible INDEX/MATCH solution presented in Harun24hr's answer instead.

There we go.   I got it to work.   I did try both the Vlookup and the index match, but following along with Harun24hr's answer I found my mistake and got it working with index match.   Thank you everyone!

Not sure why you deleted your last comment which is crucial in understanding why the presented formulas didn't work for you at the time. Nevertheless, you can select your whole range, including the headers, and use Ctrl+T to convert it to an Excel (structured) table. Now you can dynamically write the formula in the following way: =INDEX(Table1[Team],MATCH(H3,Table1[Control Code],0)).

Use XLOOKUP() function. All the following formula should work.
=VLOOKUP("120/7C/ME",A2:B6,2,FALSE)
=INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH("120/7C/ME",A2:A6,0))
=XLOOKUP("120/7C/ME",A2:A6,B2:B6)
=FILTER(B2:B6,A2:A6="120/7C/ME")



Ok, I edited my problem with the screenshot my excel isn't pretty right now... just trying to make the darn thing work! The idea is... put in the control code and have it pop out the team name. Thank you for your help... I think putting in the Screenshot is something I should have done the first time and don't know why I didn't! –
